# How to get authentication token on a server side?

Tags: python, grpc

I'm trying to implement a custom token-based auth scheme with grpc and I have the following code on the client side:

```
with open('server.crt', 'rb') as f:
    trusted_certs = f.read()

credentials = grpc.ssl_channel_credentials(root_certificates=trusted_certs)
composite_credentials = grpc.composite_channel_credentials(credentials, grpc.access_token_call_credentials("test_token"))
channel = grpc.secure_channel('{}:{}'.format('localhost', 50051), composite_credentials)
stub = helloworld_pb2_grpc.GreeterStub(channel)
response = stub.SayHello(helloworld_pb2.HelloRequest(name='test'))
```

This code works fine and seems to transmit test token to the server. However, I can't come up with a solution of how to get the token on the server side and check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case if anyone run up against the same problem, the right solution is to use:

```
context.invocation_metadata()
```

on the server side. This returns a collection of tuples that represent metadata passed on the client side (for example, "authorization" header and it's value).